# Porting Windows Solution to Linux in visual studio

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2019

i have visual studio solution for Windows os , its combination of 5 projects .
i want to port it to linux os , so i started by creating linux solution and adding the project one by one and compile it .

do i need to copy all source code/includes to the linux remote server and add includes directory to that source code or there is a way to tell visual studio to copy all external dependencies to remote linux server ?

thanks.

Comment: You can use `cmake` to generate the cross-platform solution for you, and open that from VS.

Comment: is there any other solution to do so instead of cmake ?

Comment: Plenty, but I have no interest in them.

Comment: Here are 2 alternatives to `CMake`:  SCons and QMake.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a `CMakeLists.txt` file automatically with [CMake Converter](https://cmakeconverter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html). In its simplest form, just install it from [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/pavelliavonau/cmakeconverter) or with `python -m pip install cmake-converter` and run `cmake-converter -s <path/to/file.sln>`. The generated file will probably need some tweaking, but at least you won't have to write it from scratch.

Comment: OT: Is the `CMake` generated very complex? Years ago I have attempted using some of these types of tools but gave up because the generated CMake was so complex it was not very suitable in the case were you would want to hand edit the CMake later.